# Pandas df.apply()

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df:

```
test2= pd.DataFrame({
            'A':[1, 2, 3],
            'B':[4, 5, 6],
            'C':[7, 8, 9] })
```

and I have written a simple function as:

```
def add(a,b,c):
    return a+b+c
```

Now I am using this function in my df using pandas df.apply method as:

```
test2.apply(add(test2['A'], test2['B'], test2['C']),axis=1)
```

It gives me an error saying **ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()**

But when I amend my code as:

```
test2.apply(lambda df: add(df['A'],df['B'],df['C']),axis=1)
```

it works perfectly fine, giving me results as I expected as:

```
0 12
1 15
2 18
```

My question is, why I need the lambda expression when I have already defined my function beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

It is because `apply` expects a function to apply to a `DataFrame` or a `Series`. If you call `add` on the three `Series` objects you are passing to it you don't need to call `apply` anymore at all. This is because addition is already applicable to `Series` objects. However, not every function can be applied this way, which is what `apply` is for.

The error you are getting is due to the fact that you are passing a `Series` whereas it expects a function.

Answer (score 0):

Change your signature function:

```
def add(row):
    return sum(row)

out = test2.apply(add, axis=1)
print(out)

# Output:
0    12
1    15
2    18
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Does it solve your problem?